# which UI framwork is good to use with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jquery-ui, user-interface, spring-mvc

We have developed a web application using struts2+Tiles+Hibernate. Now our requirement is we have to upgrade this application to Spring MVC+(UI Framework)+Hibernate.

I will appreciate you time if you suggest me with a good UI framework that can be used with Spring MVC. Our application is has a part in which we have to present data using charts like Bar graphs, Pie graph etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ext-js for creating your client side interface. Primafaces is also another good option

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you Primefaces. I already worked with Richfaces and missed so many cool components that Primefaces offers.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [this article](http://blog.zkoss.org/index.php/2015/11/17/rich-web-application-with-spring-mvc-crud-demo/), it used Spring MVC controller to communicate with ZK UI components. (all in Java code)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you ThymeLeaf.  ThymeLeaf is a good open source project. It's well documented and it has responsive user forums. And also Thymelef Expression Language is used more powerful than JSP Expression Language.